# Create an array of objects from img element attributes, and output values, jquery

Tags: jquery, arrays, object, supersized

Right now I have a fullscreen plug-in working with static urls, but I'd like to replace those with dynamic image data that a CMS outputs to the page.

Here is a sample of the HTML output from the CMS:

```
<ul class="large-gallery">

<li>
<a href="http://www.domain.com/urlpath34">
<img src="http://www.domain/imageurl351.jpg" data-full-src="http://www.domain/imageurl361.jpg" alt="Image Title 4725">
</a>
</li>

<li>
<a href="http://www.domain.com/urlpath34">
<img src="http://www.domain/imageurl354.jpg" data-full-src="http://www.domain/imageurl3721.jpg" alt="Image Title 73365">
</a>
</li>

<li>
<a href="http://www.domain.com/urlpath34">
<img src="http://www.domain/imageurl356.jpg" data-full-src=v"http://www.domain/imageurl3567.jpg" alt="Image Title 4635">
</a>
</li>

</ul>
```

Here is the Javascript:

```
<script type="text/javascript">// <![CDATA[

        jQuery(function($){

            $.supersized({

                // Functionality
                slide_interval          :   5000,       // Length between transitions
                                    new_window              : 0,
                transition              :   6,          // 0-None, 1-Fade, 2-Slide Top, 3-Slide Right, 4-Slide Bottom, 5-Slide Left, 6-Carousel Right, 7-Carousel Left
                transition_speed        :   1200,       // Speed of transition

                // Components                           
                slide_links             :   'blank',    // Individual links for each slide (Options: false, 'num', 'name', 'blank')
                slides                  :   [           // Slideshow Images
{image : 'http://www.domain.com/manually-inputed-image-path-url-1.jpg', title : 'Some Manual Title 1',  url : 'http://www.domain.com/manually-inputted-url-1'},
{image : 'http://www.domain.com/manually-inputed-image-path-url-2.jpg', title : 'Some Manual Title 2',  url : 'http://www.domain.com/manually-inputted-url-2'},
{image : 'http://www.domain.com/manually-inputed-image-path-url-3.jpg', title : 'Some Manual Title 3',  url : 'http://www.domain.com/manually-inputted-url-3'},
{image : 'http://www.domain.com/manually-inputed-image-path-url-4.jpg', title : 'Some Manual Title 4',  url : 'http://www.domain.com/manually-inputted-url-4'},
{image : 'http://www.domain.com/manually-inputed-image-path-url-5.jpg', title : 'Some Manual Title 5',  url : 'http://www.domain.com/manually-inputted-url-5'},
{image : 'http://www.domain.com/manually-inputed-image-path-url-6.jpg', title : 'Some Manual Title 6',  url : 'http://www.domain.com/manually-inputted-url-6'},                                             ]

            });
        });
// ]]></script>
```

What I'd like to do.

I'd like to replace this code in the javascript;

```
{image : 'http://www.domain.com/manually-inputed-image-path-url-1.jpg', title : 'Some Manual Title 1',  url : 'http://www.domain.com/manually-inputted-url-1'},
{image : 'http://www.domain.com/manually-inputed-image-path-url-2.jpg', title : 'Some Manual Title 2',  url : 'http://www.domain.com/manually-inputted-url-2'},
{image : 'http://www.domain.com/manually-inputed-image-path-url-3.jpg', title : 'Some Manual Title 3',  url : 'http://www.domain.com/manually-inputted-url-3'},
{image : 'http://www.domain.com/manually-inputed-image-path-url-4.jpg', title : 'Some Manual Title 4',  url : 'http://www.domain.com/manually-inputted-url-4'},
{image : 'http://www.domain.com/manually-inputed-image-path-url-5.jpg', title : 'Some Manual Title 5',  url : 'http://www.domain.com/manually-inputted-url-5'},
{image : 'http://www.domain.com/manually-inputed-image-path-url-6.jpg', title : 'Some Manual Title 6',  url : 'http://www.domain.com/manually-inputted-url-6'},
```

to be something like this:

```
for each bigImage, output this 
{ image : 'bigImage.imgUrl', title : ' bigImage.title ', url : ' bigImage.linkUrl '},
```

I was thinking about creating an array of objects for bigImages, and then call each object as bigImage. but im not really sure the best approach, and also I'm curious how to format it to have it work within the plug-in script.

Comment: Well, it would seem you have a deep grasp of the concept involved. What do you need help with specifically? Is it taking the HTML that you provided and turning it into the array of objects?

Comment: I want to turn the html into an array of objects with attributes for imageUrl, title, linkUrl. Then do an each loop to create the in the plug-in. It seems like the object creation and output should be pretty basic, but I've been searching and searching for a straightforward example to follow, but I can't find out. And then I need help to figure out where to place it in the plug-in code.

Comment: And what is it you're stuck on? Iterating the HTML and extrapolating the necessary data?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14338948/create-object-array-using-attributes-of-list   this is the closest I've seen. to creating the object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you need is a function that takes a collection of img elements as input and returns the desired array as output.

I might write something like this:

```
var slidesArray = function() {

  var array = [];

  $("ul.large-gallery li img").each(function() {

    var arrayItem = { image: $(this).attr('src'), title: $(this).attr('alt'), url: $(this).parent('a').attr('href') };

    array.push(arrayItem);

  });

  return array;
}
```

And then you can say in your configuration hash:

```
slides: slidesArray()
```

Comment: Ohgodwhy has generally the same idea, however, I prefer mine b/c it can be explicitly executed as opposed to prefilled on document ready.  I think his use of jQuery finders and prop/data functions is more syntactically correct, although it will have no effect on functionality as of now.

Comment: should i include the code before $.supersized function, or within it?

Comment: Indeed. `.attr()` should be replaced with `.prop()` for the purpose of your code. +1 either way, not really a huge deal.

Comment: @DillHoffman — before.  Then call slidesArray() from inside $.supersized where you are currently manually listing the array.

Answer (score 0):

```
var slds = [];

$('.large-gallery a').each(function(i,obj){
    var $this = $(obj),
        $thisImg = $this.find('img');
    slds.push({
        image: $thisImg .data('full-src'),
        title: $thisImg .prop('title'),
        url: $this.prop('href')
    })
});
```

Then simply supply `slds` as the source to slides

```
slides: slds
```

Comment: Please, *please* cache at least the `$(obj)` with this approach; and possibly the `$(obj).find('img')` too.